# How to upsert items in Flutter

Tags: list, flutter, dart

**I have a list**

```
List<String> list = ['Hello']
```

**I have TextField which has onChanged callback.**

*Question:* How I can UPSERT an item to List when TextField triggers onChanged function

*Wanted result:*
`['Hello', 'NewHello']`

---

```
onChanged: (_) {
 // What I should do with list. Thanks
}
```

Comment: change ``_`` to ``text`` and then within callback ``list.add(text)``. I mean ``onChanged: (text) { list.add(text); }``

Comment: @OMi Shah it adds a lot of items because onChanged function is working, thanks

Comment: I want to add so only one item will stay in list

Comment: It will keep adding every change, that's what it does!!

Comment: then ``list.insert(1, text);`` should work.

Comment: It will keep replacing the element at index 1 and will insert if it's empty.

Comment: thanks let me try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You need to check if the list length is 2, if it is then update the value at index 1; if the length is less then simply add the change to the list.*

Use the [add](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.14.1/dart-core/List/add.html) method on the list to insert the change.

Change `_` to `text` and then within the callback:

```
onChanged: (text) {
     list.length == 2 ? list[1] = text : list.add(text);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the Insert method is not working for this situation because it inserts, and adds a new list of items even if index exist. Like in the database I need to have something like UPSERT. Upsert updates an item on a specific index

Comment: this should work as your ``Wanted result: ['Hello', 'NewHello']``. If you want to just update the old value with new value just pass the correct index to the old element.

Comment: It gives me ```['Hello', 'Hell', 'Hel', 'He', 'H']```

Comment: @JackSpicy, my mistake. I have updated my answer. This will fulfill your need.

Comment: list is growable. So when length is increasing, it adds a new item (by your example) ```: list.add(text)``` When onChanged function triggers it gives ```'Hello', 'Hell', ...``` again. I need function that will add an item with index, and later only update it

Comment: That's what I gave you in my updated answer. Maybe you might have then made some mistake. Kindly edit your post and add your complete code with my solution.